# Scanning low resolution images with Omnipage OCR

Tags: windows, ocr

I tried scanning with Omnipage OCR (version 17) a relatively lower 
resolution image of a document that I took with my mobile phone. 
This document was intentionally not scanned (for future training of lower resolution images). 
The Omnipage program identified it as an Image and didn't convert it into text. 
I tried drawing Text Zones and Process Zones but it just didn't do anything.

Any Ideas?

Comment: To clarify, it did not return any text from the text zone? Also, can you yourself read the text in the image?